# What's the difference between the Fermi level and the electrochemical potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition, chemical-potential

I was asked in a Thermostatistics test to compute the [electrochemical potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_potential) $\mu(T)$ and the [Fermi level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level) $\epsilon_F$ for a system of non-interacting fermions, with two possible energetic states each. As far as (I tought) I knew, both concepts mean the same in this context. What's the difference between the two? What would be a correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fermi energy, $\epsilon_F$, is only equal to the chemical potential, $\mu$, when the Fermi gas is at zero temperature.  The Fermi energy basically means, "chemical potential at zero temperature".  At any other temperature you could find $\mu$ via one of the standard thermodynamic relations (i.e. as the appropriate derivative of a free energy).

Comment: Oh, that clears things up for me. Thank you for your answer.